# Can't Deserialize a Nullable KeyValuePair from JSON with ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax, serialization, nullable

The following class does not deserialize (but does serialize) using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
public class foo {
  public KeyValuePair<string, string>? bar {get;set;}
}
```

The attempt to deserialize results in a `System.NullReferenceException` when `System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject` reaches the `bar` property. (Note, that is a surmise based on the stack trace.)

Changing the property type to `KeyValuePair<string,string>` fixes the problem, but I'd like to keep the `Nullable` type if at all possible.

The JSON is exactly what you would expect:

```
{"foo": {
  "bar": {
    "Key":"Jean-Luc",
    "Value":"Picard"
  }
}}
```

Help?

Comment: The deserialization for KeyValuePair<string, string> does not fix the error above, but actually results in two empty strings for the pair. ie, the deserialization results in data loss. So the JSON above turns into a KeyValuePair of [,]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is that when the JavaScriptSerializer tries to deserialize it will create a new instance of the class (in this the KeyValuePair) and then assign the values to properties.

This causes an issue as the KeyValuePair can only have the key and values assigned as part of the constructor and not via properties so results in an empty key and value.

You will be able to resolve this and the null issue by creating a class that implements [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) and [Registering It](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx). I have used the code below to handle a standard KeyValuePair but I am sure you can extend it to handle nulls.

```
public class DictionaryJavaScriptConverter<k, v> : JavaScriptConverter
{

    public override object Deserialize(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, System.Type type, System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<k, v>((k)dictionary["Key"], (v)dictionary["Value"]);
    }

    public override System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type> SupportedTypes {
        get { return new System.Type[] { typeof(KeyValuePair<k, v>) }; }
    }
}
```

Alternately you can create a simple class that has two properties key and value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been struggling with this issue for quite a little while and I could not figure out why just about every other data type would work but not a KeyValuePair. Again, thanks, it was a straightforward and very helpful response.

Comment: I wonder, in the context of MVC 3: Is there a way to register this converter so that all JSON model binding has access to this converter?  Registering the converter with a specific instance of JavaScriptSerializer doesn't really fit in nicely with MVC 3 model binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this wrapper:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Univar.aspx

I've successfully Json serialized and deserialized the nullable KeyValue pair using it.