# JSON Nullable Deserialization Error

Tags: ajax, json, asmx, nullable

Suppose you have a simple struct, like so:

```
public struct Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

And a sample class like so:

```
public class Map
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Point? PointA { get; set; }
    ///...
}
```

Now, suppose you are passing Map via AJAX as JSON.  Question, what value should be passed for the not null scenario?

It may matter that JavaScriptSerializer is being used in a C# 3.5 ASP.NET ASMX web service.

Comment: I asked a coworker 20 minutes before posting, and he came back with this answer:
    Map: { 'PointA': { __type: "Point", X: 1, Y: 1} }
Note, this may not be exact, because I have changed the names to protect the innocent.

Comment: I don't think the JavaScriptSerializer can deal with Nullable<T> types - see question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1785283/751090

Comment: I noticed that when I was searching and overlooked the fact that the {get; set;} caused the issue.  I can easily convert to a class and move away from automatic properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is what I listed in my comment about the question.  The automatic properties were the issue.  I converted the property and the issue was resolved.